# Multivariate Kernel Density Estimation for objects with missing values

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to perform a certain numerical computation in Python with Numpy.

More specifically, I am doing a multivariate Kernel Density Estimation (KDE) in a Euclidean space of dimension `F` for objects with missing values. For each incomplete object of index "k", the kernels is no Gaussians, but a Gaussians in the subspace where `ev[k]` is `True` and a uniform distribution otherwise.

I actually do not simply want to evaluate the kernel density, but the gradient for the KDE function. The complete derivation is a bit more envolved, especially for the constants.

Here I only write down a minimal working example. The constants for example - which are scalars - would need complex calculation beforehand. They are there as stability weights or for normalizations.

```
import numpy as np

# Given:

I = 100
O = 1000
F = 10

o = np.random.random((O,F))  # Euclideanv vectors that are kind of the means of the Gaussians
ev = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(O,F)) # these represent evidence and make sure that we calculate within the respective subspace
x = np.random.random((I,F))  # positions where we want to evaulate the KDE

const1 = 1.3456
const2 = 2.3456
const3 = 3.3456
const4 = 4.3456

# My calculations:

# First we calcuate the differences between the x and o vectors
diff = o[np.newaxis, :, :] - x.reshape((-1, 1, x.shape[x.ndim - 1]))

# The following two lines might be accessible from cache:

# We calculate the squared Euclidean distance between the x and o vectors and multiply them with the respective evidence vecotrs and constants. The result is the exponents for the Gaussian kernels
nsh = np.einsum('iof,iof,of,->io', diff, diff, ev, 1 / const1)

# We calculate the Gaussian kernels and normalise them with the const2. The const3 is stability weight, to avoid overflows or underflows.
kv = const2 * np.exp(nsh + const3)

# :Might be accessible from cache

# Finally we add the kernels together and calculate the gradient:
result = np.einsum('io,iof,of->if', kv, diff, ev)
```

I was trying to optimize for speed using broadcasting in the first line `diff =` and einsum in the last line. However, as one can easily see, the first line produces a very large array `diff`. Is it possible to avoid the creation of this large array while improving the speed or at least keeping the current speed?

One idea would be to replace

```
nsh = np.einsum('iof,iof,of,->io', diff, diff, ev, 1 / const1)
```

with

```
X = x
Y = o
X_sqr = np.sum(X ** 2, axis=1)
Y_sqr = np.sum(Y ** 2, axis=1)
nsh = (X_sqr[:, np.newaxis] - 2.0 * X.dot(Y.T) + Y_sqr) / const1
```

which is much faster. However, it does not include `ev` yet, because I don't know how I have to include it, to get it right. And also it does not remove the need to create `diff`, because I still need it in the final line.

Comment: keept? You probably mean keep the speed - but keep it while something else changes? If so, what?

Comment: @Reinderien: I meant "Is it possible to avoid the creation of this large array while improving the speed or at least keeping the current speed?" Is this better to understand?

Comment: @Reinderien: I want to at least keep the current speed or improve it. But in either case I would like to not have to create the large `diff` array.

Comment: How much memory does it actually take up?

Comment: @Reinderien: Enough to be out of memory at times. It depends on the datasets my algorithm faces. `I, O, F` are here only to make a minimal working example.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! To give you a good review, we need to know *what the code is intended to achieve* - "a certain numerical calculation" isn't helpful. Please add sufficient context to your question, including a [title that summarises the *purpose* of the code](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436). We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.

Comment: @TobySpeight: Ok, I added information on what I want to do. Honestly, I fear that people are going to want to help me even less now. Alternatively I can refer to the papers that I am implementing, but I cannot imagine one being willing to read papers for my code review. Please give feedback if that was helpfull and what I should do if that was not helpfull.

Comment: Are you aware of [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/)? That one allows you to write it with an explicit loop **that is compiled** and achieves similar speeds as writing it externally with Fortran or C. Or do you want/have to stick with numpy?

Comment: @mcocdawc: I am aware of numba, but did not consider it, because I have not worked with it and wanted to avoid the learning curve. (Also, I forgot.) But thanks of reminding me! Also, I wanted to improve on the logic first: For example using the idea I presented in my question, it is possible to avoid the 3D array altogether, which is a huge plus in both numpy and numba. Improving via compilation or additional hardware usually only yields linear improvements. To improve super-linearily (e.g. using 2D arrays instead of 3D is an improvement in complexity class) one needs to improve logically.

Comment: It might help to look into the `scipy` library, which contains a [built-in for KDE estimation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html#scipy.stats.gaussian_kde).

Comment: @GZ0: It is not supporting what I am doing, see the evidence aspect.

Comment: @TobySpeight , et. al: is there enough context now or is more still needed?

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ It's a bit of a niche, but I think the question is clear enough. The main problem is that the code is still a minimal working example and we simply don't deal well with those on Code Review. " The complete derivation is a bit more envolved" We've been bitten by this before, where a review is provided that's of little to no use to OP because the actual code does things differently.

Comment: @Mast: Do you mant to see the full implementation? Or do you want to see the code with function calls (where the functions implementations are not provided)? What DO you deal with on Code Review? ""The complete derivation is a bit more envolved" We've been bitten by this before." What should I provide? A link to the respective literature or the entire implementation? What do I need to do to get this right?

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't gotten back to you earlier. We do have a FAQ on this topic: [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915). There's also [Simon's Guide for posting a good question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6429/52915).

Comment: @Mast: Thank you! I went through it. I have rewritten the question a couple of times now and since it still doesn't seem to be what you are looking for: Could you give *concrete* constructive feedback? What is the point here that you think is important and has not been met by me?

Comment: Code Review has a character limit of over 60k characters, yet your current code contains a minimum working example. Please post the real deal, the code you actually use, with enough context for us to understand what you're doing and what your gripes are with it. We don't need a full paper, although depending on what it is exactly what you're doing, it wouldn't be the worst of ideas.

Comment: Your question is not in terrible shape, apart from the code most of it looks like a decent start. But if we review this, I'll bet you get to dismiss some of the remarks by stating your actual code does it differently or that you're not interested in some of the parts because the real code isn't hindered by it. We can't see that if you don't post it.

Comment: Feel free to point out which part you need specific review of, but the rest could be required as context.

Comment: @Mast: My full code contains about 4-5 paper's worth of code. It's an entire research project / product. Besides that part are also proprietary. There is no way around abiding. Anyway, I will see what I can do.

Comment: Possibly Code Review is not the proper place for you to get a review then. Perhaps a review by your academic peers under NDA is a better option.

Comment: @Mast: I will think about it - maybe I have an idea how to present it. Thanks so far!